# Cleaning up dragon ball tags

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request

We currently have: [dragonball-xenoverse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-xenoverse) [dragonball-xenoverse-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-xenoverse-2) [dragon-ball-z-budokai-tenkaichi-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-budokai-tenkaichi-3) [dragon-ball-z-battle-of-z](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-battle-of-z) [dragonball-z-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-z-legacy) [dragon-ball-dokkan-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-dokkan-battle) [dbz-dokkan-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dbz-dokkan-battle)

I would like to purpose that we fix the "dragonball" tags to "dragon-ball" as the show and the games are technically 2 words instead of 1.

Edit: Updated to include DBZ Dokkan Battle tag that needs to be updated as well

Comment: Will that make the tags their final form? ;)

Comment: Yes. Until they decide to go Kaio-Ken x10, then Kaio-Ken x20, and then evolve into God Mode, but **after** god mode they go into Blue, then even become extra special as they develop an *Ultra Instict*. Yea, Dragon Ball forms are *coff coff* always final =)

Comment: If we kill them, we could always just call on Shenron to bring them back, also!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dragon Ball tags have now been renamed by [Robotnik](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12716/cleaning-up-dragon-ball-tags#comment40756_12721).

---

**Original Answer:**

Agreed, the Dragon Ball tags should be cleaned up for consistency.

#### Tags which should be renamed

- [dragonball-xenoverse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-xenoverse) -> [dragon-ball-xenoverse](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-xenoverse)
- [dragonball-xenoverse-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-xenoverse-2) -> [dragon-ball-xenoverse-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-xenoverse-2)
- [dragonball-z-legacy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragonball-z-legacy) -> [dragon-ball-z-the-legacy-of-goku](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-the-legacy-of-goku)
- [dbz-dokkan-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dbz-dokkan-battle) -> [dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle)

**Tags which don't need renaming**

- [dragon-ball-z-budokai-tenkaichi-3](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-budokai-tenkaichi-3)
- [dragon-ball-z-battle-of-z](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-z-battle-of-z)

---

As for [dragon-ball-dokkan-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dragon-ball-dokkan-battle), no action is needed. The tag currently has 0 questions and seems to have been a duplicate of [dbz-dokkan-battle](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dbz-dokkan-battle).

Comment: These have all now been actioned